# MEAN API request method questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'am reading the 'Getting MEAN with mongo, express, angular and node' book made by Simon Holmes. I like it alot but i had a big question which doesn't Seems to be covered in the book, he is talking about rest-api through http request (i went a bit forward in the book and saw there was a login system) and that triggered me a bit isn't it risky to do everything in http. And my other question was when you load your rest api in Heroku (and all your website) are the request in https since they force https (i know it cause i couldnt load Google font due to me making the request in http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> isn't it risky to do everything in http

It's less secure. People can read any request in plain text.

> when you load your rest api in Heroku (and all your website) are the
>   request in https

Whist you can use HTTP, you can make any request over HTTPS with no cost. When you upload your real app you will also want to configure your server to redirect to HTTPS too.

Comment: Thanks alot, and i do not need to do any modifications to my code for it to work in https ?

Comment: @NotanNimda no, generally you will want nginx, apache or heroku builds to do that for you, which is a layer between the request and the code